# Getting error as "Pyimage5" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # <-- absolute dir the script is in
        print(script_dir)
        rel_path_play = "images/play_pause.ico"
        rel_path_stop = "images/stop.png"
        rel_path_forward = "images/forward.png"
        rel_path_rewind = "images/rewind.png"
        abs_file_path_play = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path_play)
        abs_file_path_stop = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path_stop)
        abs_file_path_forward = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path_forward)
        abs_file_rewind = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path_rewind)
        self.play_pause_btn_img = Image.open(abs_file_path_play)
        self.stop_btn_img = Image.open(abs_file_path_stop)
        self.forward_btn_img = Image.open(abs_file_path_forward)
        self.rewind_btn_img = Image.open(abs_file_rewind)
        
        # Resize the Image
        self.resized_play_pause_img = self.play_pause_btn_img.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.resized_play_pausebtn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_play_pause_img)

        self.resized_play_pause_img.image = self.resized_play_pause_img

        self.resized_stop_img = self.stop_btn_img.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.resized_stopbtn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_stop_img)

        self.resized_forward_img = self.forward_btn_img.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.resized_forwardbtn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_forward_img)

        self.resized_rewind_img = self.rewind_btn_img.resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.resized_rewindbtn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_rewind_img)

       
        # Create Player Control Frame
        self.control_frame = Frame(self.root)

        self.play_pause_btn = Button(self.control_frame, image=self.resized_play_pausebtn_img, borderwidth=0,
                                     command=lambda: self.play_pause())
```

I am using python 3.9 and pycharm IDE
I tried the solution already available. nothing is working.
I am getting File

```
 "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage5" doesn't exist.
```

initially, it was working fine. I changed the code to MVC and made a separate view file for each frame. older version still working fine.

Comment: there are multiple possible failures and your code doesn't indicate any of them. Please provide a [mre] in order to get help.

Comment: Does your code create more than one instance of `Tk`?

Comment: Consider adding a link to the previous solution you tried.